# Fragment HomeMainFragment is not an active fragment of FragmentManager FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments

Back traces starts.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fragment HomeMainFragment{1c1ac1f} (b3bbebc2-f159-448d-81b8-f3818008f830) is not an active fragment of FragmentManager FragmentManager{528740d in HostCallbacks{712d49}}}
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.setMaxLifecycle(FragmentManager.java:3303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:446)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2404)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2162)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8673)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109)
```

Back traces ends.

My code snippet:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUdib.png)

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: You've called `remove` on a particular fragment, which means you cannot do anything else with that fragment. What of your code is preventing your code from calling `setMaxLifecycle` on that same fragment?